# Java: How could a breakpoint stop an applet from painting without *ever being tripped*?

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, breakpoints

In eclipse I am writing some code that crawls a specific webpage and downloads an applet, which it then adds to a JFrame and executes.  If I run program without adding any breakpoints, it works perfectly.  It loads the applet, and it begins running.  However, if I add a breakpoint to the applets update(Graphics g) method, it simply stops refreshing.  This is expected, obviously, but it never actually trips the breakpoint.

I know breakpoints are working in general with my setup, and in fact if I add a breakpoint to the `paint(Graphics g)` method of the exact same applet, it will trip whenever you would expect it to.

The only thing that is slightly unconventional about this is that I don't have the source of the applet which I am displaying.  Instead, I simply set a breakpoint on the method entry.

If I disable the breakpoint while the applet is running, it resumes painting, but if I enable it again, it won't always stop repainting.

I don't know if this could somehow be the expected behavior of eclipse/jvm, or if I have found a bug.  If it is a bug, is it a bug in eclipse or the jvm?

Answer (score 1):

Just a suggestion: could you check what version of the JVM you are executing your applet with?

There were mentions of [troubles with breakpoints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/960670/why-when-starting-gwt-in-debug-mode-my-break-points-dont-break) (also [detailed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1027002/eclipse-swing-app-breakpoint-hit-only-after-an-uncaught-exception-is-thrown/1027038#1027038)) and the latest jdk6.0_u14,
so if you are using this version, you may want to check if the same behavior is observed with [6.0_u13](http://java.sun.com/products/archive/j2se/6u13/index.html).

Comment: I am actually using
java version "1.6.0_0"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.5) (6b16-4)
OpenJDK Client VM (build 14.0-b15, mixed mode, sharing)

So I am not sure what version that corresponds to in the sun releases (I see 14, 15, and 16 in in the version numbers)
Either way, I will try installing an older version (Probably java 5) and see if I still get the bug.

Comment: And Java 5 gets the same error.

I think the problem might be that I am putting the breakpoint in a local copy of the jar, but actually loading the class from a URLClassLoader.

Comment: Nope, using a local copy, I am getting the same problem, but upon further inspection, it seems that it is not entirely stopping painting, just there is a huge lag.  Perhaps somehow adding a breakpoint is slowing it enormously.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the debug panel showing your threads.  It might well be another thread than you expect that breaks on the breakpoint.