# Eclipse is not stopping at breakpoint in my GWT application

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, gwt

I'm trying to debug a GWT application in eclipse. I click on the Debug->Web Application, and eclipse gives me a URL for development mode. Once I paste that into Firefox, where I have the GWT extension installed, eclipse spends many minutes compiling the application. However when the website loads, and I perform actions that should trigger a breakpoint, I don't seem to hit the breakpoint. Any ideas what could be causing this?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you verified with trivial test applications ("hello world") that it works in general?

Comment: Do your breakpoints in eclipse show a checkmark on the blue dot image. The image which is displayed left of the source line you put the breakpoint on?

Comment: I did test this out on other applications, and the debugging features work fine. It only seems to fail for this one project.

Comment: @Hilbrand - The breakpoints in this project show a checkmark. Other projects however show a blue dot image. What is the significance of this?

Comment: A checkmark indicates the project is linked to the debugger and means if the program passed that line it should stop at that breakpoint. So it should stop, unless the execution never comes at that breakpoint. See also the other answers for hints. If nothing else works, clean up all generated code, manual and via eclipse clean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically the problem isn't with the Eclipse or GWT. The problem may be with the JDK .

The following links can just be the solution you may be searching for :

- [GWT 2.0 Eclipse Breakpoint Not Working ?](http://groups.google.com/group/google-web-toolkit/browse_thread/thread/b1eda485b7391de0/a6384d31fcfa5059?pli=1)
- [GWT in Deug mode - Breakpoints don't break !](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/960670/why-when-starting-gwt-in-debug-mode-my-break-points-dont-break)
- [Breakpoints ingnored in GWT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1022007/why-are-my-breakpoints-ignored-with-gwt-eclipse-and-java-1-6-0-14)

Comment: I finally gave up on fixing this issue, because I was unable to solve it. However this solution was the most helpful one here, and got me quite far in identifying the problem.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you are using web mode instead of development mode. You did state that compilation takes many minutes. Compilation in dev mode does not require so much time, but compilation to JavaScript takes minutes. And as you know, you can not debug GWT client side Java code in web mode.

Comment: Well I created a run configuration, so I'm not sure what this means. However I'd think I'm running in dev mode since at the start of execution I see a google.gwt.dev_mode or something scrolling past the screen briefly when I hit the debug button.

Answer (score 0):

I just hit the problem where my server was running in debug mode, but the breakpoints were not showing as installed (check mark on the breakpoint icon). I found that was because there was already a debug connection to the JVM. When I closed the other debug connection and restarted running the project in development mode, the breakpoints started popping.