# Eclipse debug mode not opening

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

I am building a web application with Google Web Toolkit (GWT ) framework.
When i try to run the project in debug mode , it runs normally as in "run" mode itself. I dont get the debug perspective also.

To see if it was problem with my eclipse , i created a simple HelloWorld java application and the debug mode works perfectly .

In a seperate thread  with similar issue it was advised to update JDK version. Which i did , but still didnt help

[Why when starting GWT in debug mode, my break points don't break](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/960670/why-when-starting-gwt-in-debug-mode-my-break-points-dont-break)

Please help

Comment: Try changing the perspective to debug and then run in debug mode.

Comment: Maybe you're running SDM, just a whild guess here?

Answer (score 1):

Try Changing the perspective to Debug.

Windows -> Perspective ->Open Perspective ->Debug

Comment: I did that , but it still doesnt have the "step into " , "step over" buttons activated.Moreover the application has not stopped at the breakpoint also.Additional info  GWT 2.6 . Eclipse Juno, JDK 1.7 . Google Eclipse plugin com.google.gdt.eclipse.suite.4.3.update.site_3.8.0

Answer (score 0):

I was able to make the breakpoints work. Basically i was trying to put breakpoints in the onmoduleload method which is in the client side packages. Looks like debug for client side is not provided in eclipse.
I was able to put breakpoints in Serverside classes and the breakpoints were hit.
For client side apparently we can use chrome and view source and see the breakpoints.I am yet to try it